# Load data into AWS Neptune via Apache Jena: "Missing 'query' > or 'update' parameter for POST request"

Tags: java, jena, amazon-neptune

I am trying to load data from a garden-variety Spring Boot application into an AWS Neptune store, via Apache Jena (3.14.0).

The code I'm working with has been written *and works* with a few triple stores, including Anzo and Fuseki.

The setup to even get connectivity to the Neptune store from my local development environment is a Rube-Goldberg machine I'm ashamed of discussing here - however, the connectivity "works" as of now.

My problem comes specifically with loading data into the store (think POST operations).

The operation fails when loading a Jena [Model](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html), via the [RDFConnection#load(String, Model)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/rdfconnection/org/apache/jena/rdfconnection/RDFConnection.html#load(java.lang.String,org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model)) idiom.

The stack trace looks like:

```
org.apache.jena.atlas.web.HttpException: 400 - Bad Request
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.exec(HttpOp.java:1091)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:721)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.lambda$doPutPost$9(RDFConnectionRemote.java:458)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.exec(RDFConnectionRemote.java:668)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.doPutPost(RDFConnectionRemote.java:453)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.load(RDFConnectionRemote.java:366)
    at [my loading code here]
```

More helpfully maybe, the error message from the response is:

> Http exception response
> {"code":"MissingParameterException","detailedMessage":"Missing 'query'
> or 'update' parameter for POST request","requestId":"[some UUID]"}

The AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/CommonErrors.html) with regards to common errors seem to be of no use here.

The text of the error message seems clear "in a way" - the request is missing a parameter.

I haven't had a close look yet on how Jena builds the request in the first place (since my usage of the framework works fine with other triple stores), and neither do I understand how to add extra parameters, from the RDFConnection [javadoc](http://localhost:63342/digital-twin-parent/jena-rdfconnection-3.14.0-javadoc.jar/org/apache/jena/rdfconnection/RDFConnection.html).

I also haven't tried to send a SPARQL request manually to the store, e.g. via a REST client - but I want to use Jena in the first place, so it's probably not ideal to linger so far beyond.

The AWS [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-sparql-java.html) on using Neptune with Jena is very basic and only reads from the triple store - so once again, no cookie there.

Again, same stack, same code, same data, other store --> works fine.

Is there any simple way around this issue, or maybe some documentation/examples I've missed out on?

Comment: The request is using the SPARQLGraph Store Protocol (GSP), not SPARQL Query (parameter query) or SPARQL Update (parameter=update if perfomed that way).  GSP is not listed as supported for Neptune. If that is still the case, a way round this would be to convert a graph into a `INSERT DATA {}` and use SPARQL Update.

Comment: @AndyS Thanks for the hint. Still unfamiliar with a lot of the ecosystem so that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Bulk load into Netpune seems to be feasible in a two step process via RDF4J. Wrote a program to generate an RDF (NT file) and then used RDF4J console to load it manually into Neptune.

Guess : If we dig in a bit more into RDF4J and how Neptune is accepting bulk load from it, it might be feasible to do the entire load within the same program.

```
$ ./bin/console.sh
04:10:40.412 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.platform.PlatformFactory - os.name = linux
04:10:40.416 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.platform.PlatformFactory - Detected Posix platform
Connected to default data directory
RDF4J Console 3.6.3
Working dir: /home/bitnami/tools/eclipse-rdf4j-3.6.3
Type 'help' for help.
> create sparql
Please specify values for the following variables:
SPARQL query endpoint: https://yyy.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/sparql
SPARQL update endpoint: https://yyy.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/sparql
Local repository ID [endpoint@localhost]: test
Repository title [SPARQL endpoint repository @localhost]: test Graph data model PoC
Repository created
> open test

test> sparql select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10
Evaluating SPARQL query...
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| s                      | p                      | o                      |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| <https://test.com/s>   | <https://test.com/p>   | <https://test.com/o>   |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
1 result(s) (671 ms)

test> clear

test> load /home/bitnami/projects/model/sparql-client/output/model.nt
```