# Converting RDFConnection.load(String graphName, Model model) into SPARQL Update notation while specifying named graph

Tags: sparql, jena, amazon-neptune

I am working on a code base that uses Apache Jena (3.14.0) to save triples into either Anzo or Fuseki (for local testing).

I am trying to adapt the code to support AWS Neptune - see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077733/load-data-into-aws-neptune-via-apache-jena-missing-query-or-update-param?noredirect=1#comment118572622_67077733).

A fellow SO user brought my attention to the fact that Neptune does not support GSP.

The code I'm looking at persists triples with the [RDFConnection.load(String graphName, Model model)](http://localhost:63342/digital-twin-parent/jena-rdfconnection-3.14.0-javadoc.jar/org/apache/jena/rdfconnection/RDFConnection.html#load-java.lang.String-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model-) notation.

My idea was to convert it to [RDFConnection.update(Update update)](http://localhost:63342/digital-twin-parent/jena-rdfconnection-3.14.0-javadoc.jar/org/apache/jena/rdfconnection/RDFConnection.html#update-org.apache.jena.update.Update-).

In other words:

```
myRdfConnectionInstance.load( myGraphNameString, myJenaModel )
```

... would become something in the lines of:

```
myRdfConnectionInstance.update(
    new UpdateBuilder()
        .addInsert( myGraphNameString, myJenaModel )
        .build()
);
```

(`myGraphNameString` represents a URN)

My take was that this notation would employ the SPARQL update protocol as opposed to GSP, hence enabling persisting the triples in Neptune.

I was comforted in that regard by the fact that, if I omitted the named graph parameter and just invoked `.addInsert( myJenaModel )`, the request would be valid with all triple stores I tried it with.

Unfortunately the same parametrized with a named graph fails not only with Neptune, but also with my local Fuseki store.

The [javadoc](http://localhost:63342/digital-twin-parent/jena-querybuilder-3.14.0-javadoc.jar/org/apache/jena/arq/querybuilder/UpdateBuilder.html#addInsert-java.lang.Object-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model-) states:

> Add all the statements in the model a specified graph to the insert statement.[...]

... which was confusing in terms of English, but seemed to lean towards what I wanted.

I suspect the second part of the description:

> The graph object is converted by a call to makeNode().

... is where I'm messing up.

Unfortunately I happen to be neither too familiar with triple stores in depth, nor with Jena, so I don't know where to chase next.

**Questions**

- Is `RDFConnection#update` the right direction to convert the write notation to SPARQL update, hence preparing for compatibility with Neptune?
- If so, what am I missing about the parametrization of the graph name?
- If there any additional documentation that would be relevant, aside from the APIs quoted here?

**Some error messages**

The response I get from Neptune looks like (formatting added for clarity):

```
Http exception response 
{
"detailedMessage":"Malformed query: Illegal subject value: 
    \"urn:[my URN]\"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> [line 2]",
"code":"MalformedQueryException","requestId":"[some UUID]"
}
```

No explicit error message from Fuseki, just the HTTP 400.

The stack trace looks like:

```
org.apache.jena.atlas.web.HttpException: 400 - Bad Request
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.exec(HttpOp.java:1091)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:721)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:517)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:473)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.lambda$updateExec$6(RDFConnectionRemote.java:324)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.exec(RDFConnectionRemote.java:668)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.updateExec(RDFConnectionRemote.java:324)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionRemote.update(RDFConnectionRemote.java:311)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnection.update(RDFConnection.java:250)
    at [my code]
```

Comment: can you specify what "fails" mean when doing this on a Fuseki store? Do you get an exception? According to the source code, it basically can take a graph URI as string or already as a `Node_URI`.

Comment: @UninformedUser I should have added that right away, but I'm not sure how that really helps. I've edited the question to include the little error messages I have.

Comment: Is your grahp name a proper URI? Also, can you try `NodeFactory.createURI()` please as the first argument and the graph name being a proper URI? For example, `.addInsert( NodeFactory.createURI("http://example.org/g1"), myJenaModel)`

Comment: @UninformedUser it's not - as mentioned in the question, it's a URN. Do you know of any incompatibility, maybe at protocol level?

Comment: Q1: Reasonable approach. UpdateBuilder only constructs general DELETE-INSERT-WHERE requests. The form "INSERT DATA" is simply enough that it can be made by: For an ByteArrayOutputStream (1) write "INSERT DATA {\n" (2) RDFDataMgr to write N-triples (3) write "\n}". For named graphs, include a "GRAPH <uri> {" .. graph triples  ... "}".

Comment: For UpdateBuilder, you may get on better asking on users@jena.apache.org (subscribe first - see https://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/index.html)

Comment: "Http exception response" - there is a literal string in the subject position. Print the update locally to check what has been produced.

Comment: Thanks for all the info @AndyS. It's a bit late for me but I'll pick it up tomorrow first thing.

Comment: @AndyS I'm pretty sure he's giving a URN as first argument, e.g. "urn:graph1" but without the angle brackets. the `UpdateBuilder` passes this to `Converters.makeNode` which leads to a call of `NodeFactoryExtra.parseNode` which in fact fails to parse it as a `Node_URI` but throws an exception which leads to fallback call to `makeLiteral`

Comment: @Mena when using URN for the graph, you have to use angle brackets nevertheless, i.e. only using `"urn:graph1"` isn't enough - instead you have to wrap it as `"<urn:graph1>"` - so you have to do `.addInsert( String.format("<%s>", myGraphNameString), myJenaModel )` if your graph URN isn't already wrapped in between `< >` beforehand

Comment: @UninformedUser this looks promising. The URN string was, indeed, not wrapped in lt/gt brackets. It seems to be working with the new notation and parametrization, with Neptune. Will be trying around with Fuseki shortly. In the meantime, may I ask you to write down your comment as an answer? An interesting detail in there would be whether the bracket-enclosed notation for a URN graph name is a matter of protocol difference between GSP and SPARQL update or just an API difference with Jena - if I'm not vampirizing your time too much :)

Comment: The "<>" causes the string to be made into a URI, taking off the "<>".  Or pass in an object that indicate the kind of data, e.g. Resource, it will know it's a URI. For a String, it needs a hint.

Comment: I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-2093 to record using SPARQL Update instead of the Graph Store Protocol for load and put operations.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk load into Netpune seems to be feasible in a two step process via RDF4J. Wrote a program to generate an RDF (NT file) and then used RDF4J console to load it manually into Neptune.

Guess : If we dig in a bit more into RDF4J and how Neptune is accepting bulk load from it, it might be feasible to do the entire load within the same program.

```
$ ./bin/console.sh
04:10:40.412 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.platform.PlatformFactory - os.name = linux
04:10:40.416 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.rdf4j.common.platform.PlatformFactory - Detected Posix platform
Connected to default data directory
RDF4J Console 3.6.3
Working dir: /home/bitnami/tools/eclipse-rdf4j-3.6.3
Type 'help' for help.
> create sparql
Please specify values for the following variables:
SPARQL query endpoint: https://yyy.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/sparql
SPARQL update endpoint: https://yyy.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/sparql
Local repository ID [endpoint@localhost]: test
Repository title [SPARQL endpoint repository @localhost]: test Graph data model PoC
Repository created
> open test

test> sparql select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10
Evaluating SPARQL query...
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| s                      | p                      | o                      |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| <https://test.com/s>   | <https://test.com/p>   | <https://test.com/o>   |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+
1 result(s) (671 ms)

test> clear

test> load /home/bitnami/projects/model/sparql-client/output/model.nt
```